# Problema con ajuste responsive de CSS - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

Hola amigos tengo un pequeño problema, estoy haciendo uso de las unas clases boostrap, pero ¿Como hago para que la imagen se centre al momento de ejecutarlo en una pantalla móvil?.

```html
<div class=" d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col ml-md-auto">
            <img src="./cocacola.PNG" alt="Natclar" >              
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-top:30px">
            <h1>hhhshsh</h1>
          </div>
          <div>

          </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aquí la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, no entiendo cómo usas tu código de esa manera, tienes un elemento `row` y dentro de ese elemento tienes un elemento `col` con la clase `margin left - medium device - auto` y otro elemento `col` en la misma fila con la clase `large device -3 columns` y pretendes que la imágen esté centrada. Te sugiero que leas [Bootstrap - Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/) para que te familiarices un poco con Bootstrap. Saludos

Comment: Lo que estas buscando se llaman media queries ó responsive-breakpoints: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

Lo que necesitas es establecer uan para el tamaño máximo que quieres para la vista móvil y en ese bloque añadir una regla para la imagen que le haga un display:none

Comment: Posibles duplicados: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73268/centrar-una-img-responsive-bootstrap y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69174/centrar-un-div-con-bootstrap/

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Centrar una img-responsive bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73268/centrar-una-img-responsive-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

¿Como quieres centrarlo?

Porque una solución muy sencilla es usar text-center en el row y listo, tendrás centrada la imagen. Pero no sé si esa sea exactamente la forma en que buscas que se vea

Nota que al poner col sin especificar el numero de columnas, puede ser confuso, le he puesto 12, pero puedes cambiarlo.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://humantalent.hiringroom.com/data/accounts/humantalent/logos/5bbca0ec9aab463555f1d396.jpg" alt="Natclar" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 mt-4">
    <h1>hhhshsh</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: el col12 no era para tomar todo el ancho del espacio ?

Comment: sí, yo lo puse solo de ejemplo, podría ser col-lg-9 para que quedaran juntos en pantallas grandes. lo importante aqui es el text-center. Y la estructura correcta d elos divs, que está muy rara como la puso originalmente.

Answer (score 0):

intenta alinearlos con css asi

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 700px) { 

 img{
    margin:0 auto;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que solo debe ir centrado en la versión móvil, de ahí que para escritorio tenga un col-lg-3. Por ese motivo debes definir para cada breakpoint/media-query un número de columnas concreto:

```
 <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center">
   <div class="row">
           <div class="col-12 col-md-auto ml-auto">
             <img src="./cocacola.PNG" alt="Natclar" >              
           </div>
           <div class="col-12 col-md col-lg-3" style="margin-top:30px">
             <h1>hhhshsh</h1>
           </div>
           <div>

      </div>
```